# A and B are sets. Prove that if $A \subseteq B$, then $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> A and B are sets. Prove that if $A \subseteq B$, then $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$

Here's what I have so far: Let $x\in\bigcup  A=\{x\mid\exists X\in A:x\in X\}$. Therefore $x\in X$. Since $A\subseteq B$, $X\in A$ implies $X\in B$. Now I need to show why $X\in B$ implies $X\in \bigcup B$ to complete the proof.

Comment: $B \subset \cup B$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are a family of sets?

Comment: Your first step doesn't give $x\in A$; it gives $X\in A$.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my post.

Comment: @Nameless No, that's not true in general. If $B=\{\emptyset\}$, then $\bigcup B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A\subset B$.

Choose $x\in \bigcup A$ arbitrarily. $x\in\bigcup A$ if and only if there exists $X\in A$ such that $x\in X$.

Since $A\subset B$ and $X\in A$ we have $X\in B$.

Thus there exists $Y\in B$ such that $x\in Y$ (set $Y=X$) which is equivalent to $x\in\bigcup B$. Since $x\in\bigcup A$ was arbitrary we conclude $\bigcup A\subset \bigcup B$.